# Is using query.getResultList(); method affect badly on performance?

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, persistence

I'm using Java persistence API to develop a standalone software. I need to get single results as well as multiple results from database. I have several questions also,

First one is,

I'm using **query.getResultList();** method for retrieving both single result and multiple results. I want to know weather this method retrieve the entire result set or some part of the result set (like when executing a limit query, eg: *SELECT * FROM `some_db`.`some_table` LIMIT 100 OFFSET 120;*). If not, does it affect badly on performance? (In this case I'm thinking about a database which contain around 10000 records in some tables)

Second one,

What the impact between using **query.getResultList();** and **query.getSingleResult();**

Comment: `LIMIT 100 OFFSET 120` works on DB-side and slices the result. So, it doesn't matter how much rows you have total.

Comment: Yes but I' thinking handling a list filled with objects may cause some performance impact in the software side also. because **query.getResultList();** returns a List<Object> with specific object type.

Comment: I think I strongly depends on the persistence provider you are using, as the JPA spec does not contain any notes about performance optimization on either of them. So looking at the [OpenJPA code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.openjpa/openjpa-persistence/2.3.0/org/apache/openjpa/persistence/QueryImpl.java#QueryImpl.getSingleResult%28%29), the getSingleResult() even delegates to the same getResultList() method. There is a slight query hint given for optimization in case you are using a DB2 database

Comment: @Lars im using eclipselink. Thing is im new to this framework. Im developing this software while learning how to do stuff using persistance. Anyway thanks for the information and the source :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate DB-side and server-side parts.

1. If you get a 100 rows from DB-side to server-side, it does not matter for latter server-side execution how huge you table is.
2. So, you are trying to understand an overhead of `query.getResultList()` using with just one row I think. IMHO, you should not bother about that.
3. Based on [docs](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/execute) it seems that you have small difference between `query.getResultList()` and `query.getSingleResult()` when you are getting 0 rows as a result.

> **query.getSingleResult()**
>
> ... if there are no results at all a NoResultException is thrown.

**UPD**

For Persistance API try to use this way to create a query:

`getEntityManager().createQuery(query)
         .setFirstResult(offset) // offset
         .setMaxResults(limit) // limit
         .getResultList();`

Comment: I'm saying if i used some sql query to get results, I can get the chunk i want at the moment I want, for an example: If I need 100 results for a reporting purpose, I can get that specific 100 by using **LIMIT 100 OFFSET  200** or something. But I cant do that since I'm using Persistence API, I have to get all results and subList() the main list to get the 100 I want. But there will be a list which including the 100 useful results and other 9900 unwanted results. I'm asking how to get rid of that problem? does that unwanted 9900 result set cause a slow down?

Comment: Is there a faster alternative to getResultList() ?  I am loading 2 columns from a table, but totaling 700000 results all together.
It takes 75 seconds to run query.getResultList().  SQL Trace shows that query itself runs in less than 1 second.  
What else could delay the method?